# laravel 404 route not found on custom route i added in api.php

Tags: php, angular, laravel

i have searched everywhere for the answer but i can't find it anywhere. I created a laravel and angular project. everything works fine except for 2 api routes. the /partsorder and the /partsstock route do not work. they do show up in the php artisan route:list. php artisan route:clear does not fix the problem either. the order routes from that group i can access no problem.

here is the part of the api file the problem is in:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'parts'], function () {

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@index')->name('parts.index');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/partsorder', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@getPartsOrder')->name('parts.getPartsOrder');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/partsstock', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@getPartsStock')->name('parts.getPartsStock');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('{part}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@show')->name('parts.show');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@store')->name('parts.store');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->put('{part}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@update')->name('parts.update');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->delete('{part}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@destroy')->name('parts.destroy');

  });
```

this is my controller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Traits\ApiController;
use App\Http\Requests\Part\StorePart;
use App\Http\Requests\Part\UpdatePart;
use App\Http\Resources\Part\PartCollection;
use App\Http\Resources\Part\PartResource;
use App\Models\Part;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class PartController extends Controller
{
    use ApiController;

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return PartCollection
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->setMaxApiLimit(100);
        $parts = Part::paginate($this->getPaginationLimit());

        PartCollection::wrap('parts');
        return new PartCollection($parts);
    }

    
     /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return PartCollection
     */

    public function getPartsOrder()
    {
        $parts = Part::where(['order' => 1])->get();

       

        PartCollection::wrap('parts');
        return new PartCollection($parts);
    }

    
    public function getPartsStock()
    {
        $parts = Part::where(['stock' => 0])->get();

       

        PartCollection::wrap('parts');
        return new PartCollection($parts);
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  StorePart  $request
     * @return PartResource
     */
    public function store(StorePart $request)
    {
        $part = new Part([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'device_id' => $request->input('device_id'),
            'supplier' => $request->input('supplier'),
            'stock' => $request->input('stock'),
            'price' => $request->input('price'),
            'order' => $request->input('order'),
            
        ]);

       
        $part->save();

        PartResource::wrap('part');
        return new PartResource($part);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.information_schema
     *
     * @param  Part  $Part
     
     * @return PartResource
     */
    public function show(Part $part)
    {
        PartResource::wrap('part');
        return new PartResource($part);
    }





    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  UpdatePart $request
     * @param  Part        $Part
     *
     * @return PartResource
     */
    public function update(UpdatePart $request, Part $part)
    {
      

        $part->fill([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'device_id' => $request->input('device_id'),
            'supplier' => $request->input('supplier'),
            'stock' => $request->input('stock'),
            'price' => $request->input('price'),
            'order' => $request->input('order')
            
        ]);

        $part->save();

        PartResource::wrap('part');
        return new PartResource($part);
    }





    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  Part  $Part
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy(Part $part)
    {
        try {
            $part->delete();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'Unable to delete part.',
            ], 500);
        }

        return response([
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'part has been successfully deleted.',
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

this is my service from angular which sends the request (this one sends out the correct url)

```
  getPartsOrder():Observable<Part[]> {
    // console.log(localStorage.getItem('access_token'))
       return this.http.get<Part[]>(this.ApiUrl + "/partsorder", httpOptions).pipe(
         catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)),
         map((response: { parts: Part[] }) => {
                 return response.parts;
             }
         ));
     }
```

this is the error message i receive when i try to access that specific route:

```
{
    "message": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\Part] partsorder",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
    "line": 368,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
            "line": 317,
            "function": "prepareException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 51,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 172,
            "function": "handleException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 127,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "handleRequest",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php",
            "line": 44,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 695,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 670,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 636,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 625,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 166,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
            "line": 86,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 110,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 52,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

i have been trying to fix this for days now, any help would be greatly appreciated.
If you need anymore code of information please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Among these

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/partsorder', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@getPartsOrder')->name('parts.getPartsOrder');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/partsstock', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@getPartsStock')->name('parts.getPartsStock');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('{part}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@show')->name('parts.show');
```

try changing the route like this or anything of your interest

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/show/{part}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@show')->name('parts.show');
```

Might work.
Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately that did not work

Comment: sorry, try changing only this route `Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('{part}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PartController@show')->name('parts.show');`

Comment: The weird thing is, i changed the route to what you said. did not change the route in anuglar. cleared the cache from laravel and it still gives back the part without telling me the route does not excist

Comment: Mentioning of `Route::get('{part}'` at the start of the route declaration is not suggested because, laravel application can take any route you provide as {part}. Here: `Route::get('/partsstock'`) will be taken as `Route::get('{partsstock}')`.